# How to add SNR for elements in series

Tags: snr

Say I have a signal with a SNR of 100 dB. I pass it through an ADC with 16 bits. Since the ADC will have a SNR of 6*N + 1.77 dB, how can I calculate the final SNR of the signal?

Comment: Add the quantization noise of the ADC to the noise in your signal and then calculate the new SNR by dividing.

Comment: But what if I only know the SNR, i.e. the ratios and not the actual signal or noise values?

Comment: If you assume that the ADC full scale value and signal amplitude are equal (so that the whole dynamic range of the ADC is usable), then you only need the ratios.  Set the signal value to X, then  calculate the noise in terms of X.  When you divide at the end to get SNR, X will drop out.

Comment: So I get, N1 = S/100, N2 = S/98, N_total = sqrt(N1^2+N2^2). Final SNR is S/N_total. Correct?

Comment: The idea is right, although decibels do not add like that so your numbers are incorrect.